# Reduce size of "Screen Capture" DDMS for a real device (not simulator)

Tags: android, ddms, screen-capture

I am using the "screen capture device" which comes with DDMS in Eclipse, to take snapshots of my real device screen (Samsung Galaxy SIII). The problem is that the screen displayed is huge and it does not fit with my laptop's screen. Is there any way to make it smaller to can fit with my screen. I know that it is possible using an android virtual device, but what about using a real device?

Thanks in advance

Comment: save this image in your laptop. it will re-size automatically when you view it.

Comment: In DDMS, it shows you the actual size of the image show on device screen, it cannot be redced. Using a small sized real phone can only solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Save the image in Your local System. It will Automatically reduce Size when you View it. It Worked For me.